# vb.net application cannot access my.settings when started by another program

Tags: windows, vb.net, security, my.settings

I wrote an application that stores some settings in My.Settings in order to be used within the Application_StartUp event if e.Args has some specific data.

My problem is that the software should run automatically when started by another software but it seems that it cannot access My.Settings if it is started like that.

I guess that this is some Windows Security Police ...

Does anyone have an idea how I can work around this problem?

PS: I already tried to save the information in an XML file and load it while start up. But this also did not seem to work ...

@nbk There is not much to show:

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Dim Folder As String = My.Settings.BaseDirectory & "\Results\"
    
    If (My.Settings.SubDirectory.Length > 0) Then
        Folder &= My.Settings.SubDirectory & "\"
    End If
End Sub
```

If I just run my application Folder looks like "C:\BaseFolder\Results\SubFolder" but if I try to run it via another software (which I did not write) it just looks like "\Results"

---

I wrote this console app:

```vb
Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim args = My.Application.CommandLineArgs
        If args.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception("No Result given")

        Dim executable As String = "C:\Path\Executable.exe"
        If Not File.Exists(executable) Then Throw New Exception("Executable not found")

        Dim path = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable)
        If Not Directory.Exists(path) Then Throw New Exception("Working directory not found")

        Dim result As String = String.Join(" ", args)

        Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo(executable, Chr(34) & result & Chr(34)) With {
            .UseShellExecute = True,
            .WorkingDirectory = path
        }
        Dim p = Process.Start(info)
        p.WaitForExit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

If I run it separately it works, but if I try to run it via the third party software it does not work ...

Comment: can you please add some code what you tried

Comment: Is this an application- or user-scoped setting? How are you starting it from the other app? Are you setting the working directory?

Comment: This is a user-scoped setting and I start it in an app that has an option within to run external software after processing data. In order to choose the software you want to run you select your executable and define your parameters. So I cannot tell if the software sets the working directory for me.

Comment: Small code review comment that isn't related to your problems: I would suggest composing a folder path using `System.IO.Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: I admit that `Dim Folder As String = Path.Combine(My.Settings.BaseDirectory, "Results", My.Settings.SubDirectory)` looks much better. Thanks

Comment: If it's a user-scoped setting then there will be different values for each Windows user account. Is the other app running under the same user account as you are running your app under directly? Are the values you are expecting being set when the app is run or are they default values set in the project?

Comment: It is the same user account. If I start my app directly everything works. If I close it and start it in the same user account via the third-party software, the settings are empty. Exactly the same thing happens when I save the settings to an XML and try to load it on start up.

Comment: If you create a new app of your own to run your existing app, does the same thing happen?

Comment: That was my thought when I woke up this morning and I'm going to try it out today.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I wrote the console app I added to my question. It works as standalone but I cannot use it within the thirdparty software to run my other application ...

Comment: So you're saying that your original app runs correctly if you run it directly or if you run it from another app of your own creation, but it doesn't work when run from this third-party app? In that case, the issue is with how the third-party app is running your app. We can't really diagnose the issue if we don't know anything about that.